# Странное поведение функции toFixed

Tags: javascript

Вот я обрезаю одно число:

```
const x = 123.4567;
console.log(x.toFixed(2));
```

На выходе получаем 123.45. А теперь другое:

```
const y = 122.999877;
console.log(y.toFixed(2));
```

И на выходе получаем 123.00. Что за прикол??? Почему он его округлил? Мне не нужно этого! Я хочу получить 122.99!

Comment: это не прикол, это спецификация
_Число округляется при необходимости, а дробная часть дополняется нулями таким образом, чтобы иметь указанную длину._

Comment: @ThisMan а как мне обрезать без округления?

Comment: 123.4567.toFixed(2) равен 123.46, кстати.

Comment: @NeedHate тем более...

Comment: обрежьте как строку оставив 2 символа после точки

Comment: @JurijJazdanov а если там не будет точки? Вдруг число будет без дробной части?

Comment: @ПЭХАПЭШНИК тогда это уже другой вопрос где toFixed(2) не имело бы смысла

Comment: @JurijJazdanov я не знаю что там имеет смысл. Я вообще редко пишу на js. Мне просто надо обрезать это число

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187146/truncate-number-to-two-decimal-places-without-rounding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так можно:

```js
console.log(clip(4954.373, 1)); // 4954.3
console.log(clip(4189.98628, 2)); // 4189.98
console.log(clip(1158.897094, 5)); // 1158.89709

function clip(n, a) {
  let k = Math.pow(10, a);
  return Math.floor(n*k)/k;
}
```

Comment: Да, вроде этот вариант тоже работает, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Короче я соорудил вот такую конструкцию и вроде это работает:

```
function round(value, precision = 2) {
    const str = value.toString();
    const pointPos = str.indexOf('.');
    return +(pointPos >= 0 ? str.slice(0, pointPos + precision + 1) : str);
}
```